# Adjusting mailmerge code to run in the same sheet

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

i have develped a code with the help of Google API mailmerge LINK: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/mail-merge

It works great but the problem is it creates a different sheet for each row, how can i make it create the rows in the same sheet?

Template link: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eSt7mK17zwze8UcM65zA8OOGI0kPK6n-QaTZ6Rra1r4/edit?usp=sharing

sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zTZRO27k_f5YsX9zkUXjsmuHsGvYdjDntUk0cJHLDog/edit#gid=1089207158

Full code of my project: https://github.com/EyadZaeim/MDS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Sudhu you can find full code at https://github.com/EyadZaeim/MDS